# VIM duplicates text I type

Tags: vim

I have found that occasionally when I am hitting esc to enter back into normal mode with VIM after typing some text, the text I just typed will be duplicated 2 or more times.

I'd love to know what is causing this so I can avoid it.

Using VIM within iTerm2 on OSX 10.7.3 if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That usually happens if you hit a number key (<kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>) by accident before you went to insert mode. Try <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. That will give you

```
AbAbAbAbAbAbAbAbAb
```

But it's all correct: It tells `vim` to insert `Ab` 9 times. It's as with every `vim` command, if you place a number `N` before the command, `vim` repeats the action `N` times.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably what it was.

Answer (score 6):

If you type a number before you hit <kbd>I</kbd>, whatever you insert will be repeated that many times.  For example, if you say <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>`stuff`<kbd>Esc</kbd>, you'll end up with `stuffstuffstuff`.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably what it was.